# How do I remove a directory subtree from the staging area?

Tags: git, gitignore, git-add

I made a new repository, and ran `git add -A`. I then noticed that there was a folder containing about 100 files that shouldn't have been included, so I added it to `.gitignore`.

How do I now clear the staging area so that I can `add` all my files again taking into account the updated `.gitignore`?

Comment: If you've NOT done your first commit yet, blow away the .git folder. Create the .gitignore file with the right contents. Start over. git init, stage, commit.

Answer (score 186, accepted):

In #git, you said you unintentionally added a directory that should have been ignored, so run

```
git rm --cached -r directory-name
```

to recursively remove the tree rooted at `directory-name` from the index.

Don't forget to update `.gitignore`!

Comment: Would `-r .` be simpler and do the same thing?

Comment: can you mention why the --cached is necessary? I don't see why it is

Comment: @AlexMills The question specified a directory that had been added using `git add` to the staging area, also known as the cache or index. According to the [`git rm` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm) on `--cached`: “Use this option to unstage and remove paths only from the index. Working tree files, whether modified or not, will be left alone.”

Answer (score 30):

You can just use the command:

```
git reset
```

Comment: `fatal: Failed to resolve 'HEAD' as a valid ref.` I assume there's nothing to reset *to* yet?

Comment: @Acorn, right.  I didn't realize you haven't committed at all to the new repo yet.

Comment: In that case I'd just `rm -rf .git && git init .` and start over.

Comment: This will reset everything instead of only the specific folder.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you remember to put the `s` in `--global core.excludesfile .gitignore.txt`

`excludesfile`  vs `excludefile`

Maybe this will save someone else the hour I lost...

Answer (score 1):

With a fairly modern git version you can now do:

```
git reset foldername/*
```

I found earliest documentation for this feature from version 2.12.5 onwards, but it might work on older version of git too.